# Probability that one of the tickets is number 7 and none number 18?

Tags: probability

> There are 20 tickets marked $1$ to $20$. Three tickets are drawn from it. The probability that one of the tickets is number $7$ and none are of number $18$ is?

My solution:

There are $6$ ways of arranging the three drawn tickets.
So, the  required probability is $$ 6[(1/20)×(18/19)×(17/18)].$$
Using the multiplication theorem, this equals $51/190.$

But, the Correct Answer given is $51/380$.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title, use *MathJax*, and show your work.

Comment: There are $\binom {20}3$ unrestricted ways to draw the three tickets.  there are $\binom {18}2$ triples of the form you specify.

Comment: It’s important to show your work directly in the question, not via a link.

Comment: @lulu Don’t you have to multiply by $3$ to account for the possibilities that $7$ is drawn in first, second, or third position?

Comment: @RobertShore  I am working with unordered triples.  You can, of course, use ordered ones but all that does is multiply numerator and denominator by $3!$  I am, of course, assuming that the tickets are drawn without replacement.

Comment: You may treat order in which you pull the tickets as relevant.  You may treat order in which you pull the tickets as irrelevant.  What matters is that you are *consistent* with how you do so for both numerators and denominators and that you do not overcount certain scenarios.  @ OP Here, you have if we ignore the $6$ out front, the possibility of pulling ticket 7, pulling ticket 2, and *then* pulling ticket 3.  You  have as a different possibility, pulling ticket 7, pulling ticket 3, and *then* pulling ticket 2... But accounting for re-ording was what that multiplication by 6 was meant to do

Comment: The punchline is that you (@ OP) accounted for the different orders of pulling the second and third ticket *amongst themselves* twice... once in your setup and again when you multiplied by $3!$, which threw the answer off by a factor of $2$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I didn't understood that where I have accounted for possible orders twice, can you please elaborate that further?

Comment: I would have phrased it as six arrangements, but that when we were choosing the numbers to be listed in the "second and third slots" we needed to choose them simultaneously and not one after another... as alluded to already with the $\binom{18}{2}$ mentioned by lulu.  This is because after all is said and done and we have rearranged them, we can no longer tell which was the "second" number versus the "third" number at the time of selection.

Comment: @JMoravitz But even if we choose them simultaneously, ther still exists orders and possibilities?

Comment: If it is still difficult to see how your answer was wrong, then consider the related problem... "*There are* **3** *tickets marked 1 to* **3** . *Three tickets are drawn from it. The probability that one of the tickets is number* **1**  *and none are of number 18 is?*"  It should be obvious the answer here is $1$ as every way of drawing three tickets will have the ticket marked number 1 and none of the tickets were marked number 18.  Your erroneous approach would give an answer of $3!\times\left(\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{2}{2}\times\frac{1}{1}\right)=2$.  Try charting the possibilities.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok sir, thank you so much, the example of three tickets cleared my doubt. Thank you so much☺️

Answer (score 4):

You need to be very careful here.

The simplest way would be to compute it in the typical hypergeometric way, viz $$\dfrac{\binom11\binom{18}2}{\binom{20}3} =\; \frac{51}{380}$$

If you wish to go by the multiplication route, you need to understand that among the numbers *available for selection*, there are two **types**, $7$ and "others" in which $7$ can be placed in $\binom31$ ways, thus

$$\binom31\frac{1}{20}\frac{18}{19}\frac{17}{18} = \frac{51}{380}$$

Comment: There was a typo in your attempt which I have corrected along with proper way of writing multiplication by fractions

Comment: Thank you so much sir for the explanation ☺️

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ :)